# How save record file use AVAssetWriter

Tags: audio, avassetwriter

I have use `AVCaptureSession` to capture audio data from mic,and

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

this method will return audio data,How to save the `samleBuffer` into a `AAC`format audio file.